# How to use selection to validate multiple values in java class?

Tags: java, class, constructor, boolean, selection

I am working on a virtual dog class in java. The dog should increase and/or decrease certain attributes such as hygiene, happiness, and energy based on certain actions such as eating, cleaning, and playing. All the dog's attributes should be in the range of 1-100 only (This is where I have issue figuring it out). If they exceed that range, a warning restriction message should play.
I have tried the following code and many more before this, but I always seem to get something wrong like minus numbers mostly.

Here is my full code, please ignore the main class and the main method and take a look at the VirtualPet class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VirtualPetProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialize the Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option;

        // Start the user experience
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Virtual Pet Program!");
        System.out.print("What would you like to name your pet? ");

        VirtualPet pet = new VirtualPet(input.nextLine());

        do {
            System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Please enter the integer for the option you choose:");
            System.out.println("  1. Check statuses");
            System.out.println("  2. Feed your virtual pet");
            System.out.println("  3. Play with your virtual pet");
            System.out.println("  4. Clean your virtual pet");
            System.out.println("  5. End program");
            System.out.print("\nYour choice: ");

            // Get the choice from the user.
            option = input.nextInt();

            switch (option) {
                case 1:     // Check statuses
                    // Retrieve the values using the Getter methods.
                    System.out.println("\nValues for " + pet.getName());
                    System.out.println("  Happiness: " + pet.getHappiness());
                    System.out.println("  Energy: " + pet.getEnergy());
                    System.out.println("  Hygiene: " + pet.getHygiene());
                    break;
                case 2:     // Feed your virtual pet
                    // Call feed() instance method. VirtualPet's feed() method should be doing all the work.
                    if (pet.feed()) {
                        System.out.println("\nYou fed " + pet.getName() + ".");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("\nYou couldn't feed " + pet.getName() + " due to a restriction.");
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:     // Play with your virtual pet
                    // Call play() instance method. VirtualPet's play() method should be doing all the work.
                    if (pet.play()) {
                        System.out.println("\nYou played with " + pet.getName() + ".");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("\nYou couldn't play with " + pet.getName() + " due to a restriction.");
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:     // Clean your virtual pet
                    // Call clean() instance method. VirtualPet's clean() method should be doing all the work.
                    if (pet.clean()) {
                        System.out.println("\nYou cleaned " + pet.getName() + ".");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("\nYou couldn't clean " + pet.getName() + " due to a restriction.");
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:     // End program
                    // Display a summary depending on how high the happiness is.
                    System.out.println("Thank you for playing! Here is a summary of your pet's experience:");
                    if (pet.getHappiness() >= 100) {
                        System.out.println("  You did a PERFECT job! Your pet loves you!");
                    } else if (pet.getHappiness() >= 80) {
                        System.out.println("  You did pretty well! Your pet likes you.");
                    } else if (pet.getHappiness() >= 60) {
                        System.out.println("  You did okay. Your pet isn't as happy as it could be.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("  You could have done a lot better. Your pet isn't very happy.");
                    }
                    break;
                default:        // User selected an invalid option.
                    System.out.println("\nPlease select a valid option.");
            }
        } while (option != 5);

    }
}


class VirtualPet {
//the attributes should start with the following values:
    private int happiness = 25;
    private int hygiene = 50;
    private int energy = 25;
    private String name;
    public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "Jackie";

//the constructor
    public VirtualPet(int newHappiness, int newHygiene, int newEnergy) {
        happiness = newHappiness;
        hygiene = newHygiene;
        energy = newEnergy;
    }

// the constructor for the name
    public VirtualPet(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

//getter and setter method to keep the dog's
//name below 30 characters otherwise it
//invokes the default name.
// I tried to use a separate method for setter
// but for some reason, it didn't work.
//if you have ideas about this issue, I would appreciate it.

    public String getName() {
        if (name.length() < 30) {
            return name;
        } else {
            name = DEFAULT_NAME;
        }
        return name;
    }

    public int getHappiness() {
        return happiness;
    }

    public void setHappiness(int newHappiness) {
        happiness = newHappiness;
    }

    public int getHygiene() {
        return hygiene;
    }

    public void setHygiene(int newHygiene) {
        hygiene = newHygiene;
    }

    public int getEnergy() {
        return energy;
    }

    public void setEnergy(int newEnergy) {
        energy = newEnergy;
    }

// This is where I set up a boolean method
//to return true and increase both happiness
//and energy if the energy is less than 80.
//the upgrade method called here should work
//as validation for the range of the
//attributes between 1-100.

    public boolean feed() {
        upgrade();
        if (energy < 80) {
            happiness += 5;
            energy += 30;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean play() {
        upgrade();
        if (energy > 30) {
            happiness += 20;
            energy -= 15;
            hygiene -= 30;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    public boolean clean() {
        upgrade();
        if (energy < 70) {
            happiness -= 20;
            hygiene += 50;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

// This is the method to validate
//the range of the attributes from 1-100.
//I can't see where or what I am doing wrong

    public boolean upgrade() {
        if (happiness > 0 && happiness < 100) {
            return true;
        }
        if (energy > 0 && energy < 100){
            return true;
        }
        if (hygiene > 0 && hygiene < 100){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the poiont of upgrade method. It returns a boolean which say wheter the attributes are in range or not, but you never use the output of that method.
You could modify the method that update attributes like this:

```
    public boolean feed() {
        if (energy < 80) {
            happiness += 5;
            energy += 30;
        }
        return upgrade();
    }

    public boolean play() {
        if (energy > 30) {
            happiness += 20;
            energy -= 15;
            hygiene -= 30;
        {
        return upgrade();

    }

    public boolean clean() {
        if (energy < 70) {
            happiness -= 20;
            hygiene += 50;
        {
        return upgrade();
    }

// This is the method to validate
//the range of the attributes from 1-100.
//I can't see where or what I am doing wrong

    public boolean upgrade() {
        if (happiness > 0 && happiness < 100) {
            return true;
        }
        if (energy > 0 && energy < 100){
            return true;
        }
        if (hygiene > 0 && hygiene < 100){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In this way after updating the attributes you run the upgrade() method which checks the attributes' values and returns the proper boolean to the switch case.
However you will still have the attributes out of range in this way. One silly way to solve this is to modify also the update method as follows:

```
public boolean upgrade() {
        boolean isInRange=true;
        
        if(happiness>100){
            happiness=100;
            isInRange=false;
        }
        if(happiness<0){
            happiness=0;
            isInRange=false;
        }
        if(energy>100){
            energy=100;
            isInRange=false;
        }
        if(energy<0){
            energy=0;
            isInRange=false;
        }
        if(hygiene>100){
            hygiene=100;
            isInRange=false;
        }
        if(hygiene<0){
            hygiene=0;
            isInRange=false;
        }
        
        return isInRange;
    }
```

Comment: I have already set the message in the switch statement in the main method. The values of happiness and others shouldn't keep updating when the message is shown. So the upgrade method is supposed to return false to prevent the values of happiness and other from going beyond the range of 1-100.

Comment: The upgrade method returns false but you never use that returned value, see? For instance in method clean you call upgrade but the return value of that call is then lost because you don't store it in any variable or use it anywhere.

Comment: According to the way you built the switch statement, each method (play, clean, feed) must return the boolean that says if the new value is in range, not "upgrade"

Comment: How can I implement the range function in this case?

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if that works and it's clear

Comment: It works great for the entire validation except for the feed method validation. For some reason, it stops updating before reaching 100 and it doesn't display the restriction message. You're awesome! Thank you so much though.

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful :) I don't really get what's your issue right now, if you explain better we can solve it

Comment: :) Thank you! Well now when I run the program and choose number 2 to feed the dog, it keeps replying you fed the dog and never displaying the message indicating that we couldn't feed the dog due to a restriction (See switch statement case 2). This is only applicable when I invoke feed. The other methods seem to work perfectly fine.

Comment: You're welcome ^^ . Sadly I can't figure the problem out, I don't understand why it behaves like that